# Change Drawing Order for Combined Charts in iOS Charts

Tags: ios, swift, charts, drawing, ios-charts

I am using the charts framework from [Danielgindi](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) to present data to the user.  What I am wanting to do is display two charts on top of each other using `CombinedChartView`.  The two charts are a `BarChartDataSet` and `LineChartDataSet`.  I can successfully display both sets of data, however I can't seem to control the drawing order.  The bar `BarChartDataSet` is always drawn behind the `LineChartDataSet`.  I want this order to be reversed and have the `LineChartDataSet` in the back (including any fills that I apply to it).

**My Question**

How can I change the draw order for `CombinedChartView` to make the line charts in the back and not front?

Here is my code:

```
// barDataEntries and lineDataEntries are generated in a different section and are not relevant to this question. Any data will do.
// barDataEntries is of type [BarChartDataEntry]()
// lineDataEntries is of type [ChartDataEntry]()
let barChartSet = BarChartDataSet(yVals: barDataEntries, label: "The Bars")
let lineChartSet = LineChartDataSet(yVals: lineDataEntries, label: "The Line")
barChartSet.barShadowColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0)  // If alpha is > 0, then grey bars will appear.

// Cosmetic changes for the line chart
lineChartSet.mode = .CubicBezier
lineChartSet.lineWidth = 5.0
lineChartSet.drawCirclesEnabled = false
lineChartSet.drawFilledEnabled = true
lineChartSet.colors = [UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 1, alpha: 0.0)]
lineChartSet.fillColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0)
lineChartSet.fillAlpha = 0.8

// Organizing data for statsChartViewController
let data = CombinedChartData(xVals: xAxis)
data.lineData = LineChartData(xVals: xAxis, dataSets: [lineChartSet])
data.barData = BarChartData(xVals: xAxis, dataSets: [barChartSet])

// statsChartViewController is of type CombinedChartView
statsChartViewController.data = data
statsChartViewController.leftAxis.axisMinValue = 0
```

Here is what I am getting:

[image: Bar and line chart view]

Comment: Can you show how you're adding the charts to your finale UIView ?

Comment: The chart (it's technically only one), is defined in a storyboard as a `View` set to the class `CombinedChartView`. In the `ViewController` (contains all the code mentioned above), the `View` from the story board is linked with an IBOutlet `@IBOutlet weak var statsChartViewController: CombinedChartView!`  The `BarChartDataSet ` and `LineChartDataSet ` are not individually placed in the story board; only `CombinedChartView ` is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After looking though the [source code](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/blob/master/Charts/Classes/Charts/CombinedChartView.swift), I found a solution that allows you to change the draw order.  The class `CombinedChartView` has a public enum that is responsible for the draw order:

```
public enum DrawOrder: Int
{
    case Bar       // 0
    case Bubble    // 1
    case Line      // 2
    case Candle    // 3
    case Scatter   // 4
}
```

You can change the draw order by setting an array of Ints for `drawOrder` in the order you want the objects to be drawn.  In the example below (taken from the code above), the bars will be in front of the lines:

```
// 2 is the line and 0 is the bar. 2 is drawn first, then 0 follows.
statsChartViewController.drawOrder = [2, 0]
statsChartViewController.data = data
```

This is the only modification that needs to be made.  One thing important to remember, set the draw order *before* you set the data.  If you don't, the draw order will remain the same as before.  Here are the new results:

[image]